# Hreflang conflicts with canonical in source code

Tags: canonical-url, rel-canonical, hreflang

A report in SEMRush has flagged an issue with hreflang conflicting with rel=canonical but I'm not sure how to resolve the issue or get to the bottom of it.  Has anyone else experienced this and can you shed any light on this?

Comment: It may help to share details of the error from SEMRush. It's not obvious what is meant here by "conflicting".

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you are using WordPress. Probably the easiest solution will be to make the pages that are based on tags to be excluded from sitemap and disallow those pages in robots.txt